# Obtain $x$ from exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm looking for $x$ from the following equation:

$$\frac1{(1+x)^{\frac1{p}}}+\frac1{(1+x)^{\frac2{p}}} + \cdots \frac1{(1+x)^{\frac{n}{p}}} = 0$$

Or, what's the same:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{(1+x)^{\frac{i}{p}}} = 0 $$

where $n$ and $p$ are given (say, $n=16$ and $p=52$, for example)

Is there a way to get $x$ from this?

Comment: you haven't written an equation

Comment: Looks like a geometric sum to me

Comment: your question is nonsense as long as you don't provide a value for your sum(is it equal to some y ?), which is computable since it's geometric

Comment: there's the equation, sorry for the mistake

Comment: I don't think you are really wanting to find $x$ such that  that sum is $=0$. Looks like some kind of Present Value calculation. Then $x$ will be positive, so the sum will not be $0$. No calculation needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have an expression, which can be rewritten using the geometric series, but $x$ is not determined by it. You may actually choose any $x$ but $-1$, since the sum is finite.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1+x)^{k/p}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}((1+x)^{-1/p})^k=(1+x)^{-1/p}\frac{1-(1+x)^{-(n+1)/p}}{1-(1+x)^{-1/p}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=\frac{1}{(1+x)^{1/p}}$. Let $$S=\sum_{i=1}^{n} z^i = z \frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$$

Solving for $z$ in terms of $S$ is not easy. You are trying to solve the polynomial equation:

$$z^{n+1} -(S+1)z+S = 0, 0<z<1$$

That is going to be difficult to come up with an exact solution, only approximation is going to be possible, I suspect.

Once you've solved for $z$, you get $x=z^{-p}-1$.

Comment: The iteration $z_{k + 1} = ((S + 1) z_k - S)^{1/(n + 1)}$ with starting point $z_0 = S / n$ should do fine.

Comment: Are you sure that won't converge to $z=1$, @vonbrand?

Comment: Yes, it might be better to start with $z_0 = 0$. And/or use Newton: $z_{k + 1} = z_k - (z_k^{n + 1} - (S + 1) z_k + S)/((n + 1) z_k^n - (S + 1))$.

Comment: Yeah, your first iterator gives a negative value for $(S+1)z_0-S$ when $S=10$ and $n=12$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put $$r=\frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}},$$ so that your sum is $$\sum_{i=1}^n r^i.\tag{1}$$ Now, in the case that $x=-1,$ $r$ isn't even defined, so we must have $x\ne-1$. Moreover, if $p$ is even, then we must have $x>-1$. Now, multiplying $(1)$ by the non-zero value $r-1$ gives us $$\begin{align}(r-1)\sum_{i=1}^nr^i &= \sum_{i=1}^n(r-1)r^i\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^nr^{i+1}-r^i\\ &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^nr^{i+1}\right)- \left(\sum_{i=1}^nr^i\right)\\ &= \left(\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}r^i\right)- \left(\sum_{i=1}^nr^i\right)\\ &= r^{n+1}-r,\end{align}$$ so $$\sum_{i=1}^nr^i = \frac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1},$$ and resubstitution yields $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{(1+x)^{i/p}}=\cfrac{\frac1{(1+x)^{(n+1)/p}}-\frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}}}{\frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}}-1}.\tag{2}$$

---

Since you want your expression equal to $0$, then we need the numerator in $(2)$ to be $0$ (and the denominator to be nonzero), so we need $$ \frac1{(1+x)^{(n+1)/p}}-\frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}}=0.$$ Note that we can't have $$ \frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}}=0,$$ no matter what we pick for $x,n,p.$ (Why?) Factoring gets us $$\frac1{(1+x)^{1/p}}\left(\frac1{(1+x)^{n/p}}-1\right)=0,$$ whence $$\frac1{(1+x)^{n/p}}=1,$$ so $$(1+x)^{n/p}=1.$$ Can you get the rest of the way? Remember that our solution must not make the denominator of $(2)$ become $0$, so depending on $n$ and $p$, we may have no solution.

Comment: I've edited the original post, you are right. I've included the value of 0 to the expression

Comment: See my edited answer.